# In React Native why is the const type used for in for example: const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;?

Tags: javascript, react-native, types, stack-navigator

I am working on a project for school and using react native. Admittedly I am on the novice side with regards to JavaScript. I do not understand why in the [React Navigation tutorial](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/basic-app) they use the const type.

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello, Chat App!</Text>
        <Button
          onPress={() => navigate('Chat')}
          title="Chat with Lucy"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And so my question is: Is there an particular or important reason why the const type is used for `const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;`

Comment: Why not? The `navigate` function is not going to be altered in any way. It's simply a shorthand so you can write `navigate('Chat')` rather than the full identifier.

Answer (score 4):

The `const` keyword is used when you want to create a **Constant** variable. Constants are like the variables you are probably used to, except they cannot be modified.

It's being used here because the variable is not being changed inside the `render` method of your component. If the `props` change, then the component will be re-rendered and variable will be re-created.

Comment: Thank you, is there a reason in this React Native Stack Navigator example that it should be a const type vs. a var?

Comment: @ChristopherReyes They use `const` here because you don't want to accidentally overwrite `navigate` when you're building out your `render` method. This is why Type Systems (in languages like Swift and TypeScript) are awesome!

Comment: thank you! That seems obvious now, but this answer helps to understand.

Comment: Just to clarify more on your question, you can totally use `let` or `var` and it will still work. `const` is just the best to use in this scenario because you want to declare a constant and not allow it to be overwritten.